# Give the example of p-adic lattice

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I need to give an example of $\mathbb Z_p$(p-adic integers) lattice $N$ in $\mathbb Q_p\oplus\mathbb Q_p$ ($\mathbb Q_p$ - p-adic numbers), such that discriminant:
$$\mathfrak{d}_{\mathbb Z_p}(N)\neq
\mathfrak{d}_{\mathbb Z_p}
(\pi_1(N))\mathfrak{d}_{\mathbb Z_p}
(\pi_2(N)),$$
where $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ - projection of $N$ on the first and second components of  $\mathbb Q_p\oplus\mathbb Q_p$.

My attempt:
Discriminant by definition is determinant of the Gram matrix of basis $N$. So, the Gram matrix must be not diagonalizable.
Then we need to find such example of p-adic integers free module $N$ in $\mathbb Q_p\oplus\mathbb Q_p$ such that $Tr(e_ie_j)$ is not diagonalizable, where $e_i$ - basis of $N$ in $\mathbb Q_p\oplus\mathbb Q_p$.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

$$N = (a,b)\Bbb{Z}_p\oplus (c,d)\Bbb{Z}_p, \qquad a,b,c,d\in \Bbb{Q}_p,ad-bc\ne 0$$

$Disc(N)$ is the image of $ \det(\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d})^2= (ad-bc)^2$ in $\Bbb{Q}_p^*/ (\Bbb{Z}_p^\times)^2$, note that it doesn't depend on the chosen basis of $N$ (which can be changed with a multiplication by a $GL_2(\Bbb{Z}_p)$ matrix, whose determinant is in $\Bbb{Z}_p^\times$).

$ad-bc=p^{v_p(ad-bc)} u$ with $u\in \Bbb{Z}_p^\times$ so $$Disc(N)=p^{2 v_p(ad-bc)}$$
Next
$$\pi_1(N) = p^{\min (v_p(a),v_p(c))}\Bbb{Z}_p,\qquad Disc(\pi_1(N))= p^{2\min (v_p(a),v_p(c))}$$ and similarly $Disc(\pi_2(N)) = p^{2\min (v_p(b),v_p(d))}$.

Whence you want $$v_p(ad-bc)\ne \min (v_p(a),v_p(c))+\min (v_p(b),v_p(d))$$

For this take $$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} = \pmatrix{1&1+p\\1&1}$$

Comment: thank you for the answer! I have only one question - why $Disc(N)$ is the image of $ \det(\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d})^2= (ad-bc)^2$ in $\Bbb{Q}_p^*/ (\Bbb{Z}_p^\times)^2$?

Comment: What is your definition of $Disc(N)$ ?

Comment: $\mathfrak d_{\mathcal O}(N)\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=} (D_{\mathcal O}(N) : N)_{\mathcal O}$. For free modules $\mathfrak d_{\mathcal O}(N)=\det(Tr(e_ie_j))$

Comment: A definition, not more meaningless symbols

Comment: It's index of dual lattice to lattice. For free modules it's determinant of Gram matrix of the lattice basis

Comment: Your lattice is $L=M\Bbb{Z}_p^2\subset \Bbb{Q}_p^2$, it inherits the standard bilinear form $\Bbb{Q}_p^2\times \Bbb{Q}_p^2\to \Bbb{Q}_p$, $b(x,y)=x^\top y$, the dual lattice is $L' = \{ x\in \Bbb{Q}_p^2, \forall y\in L, b(x,y)\in \Bbb{Z}_p\}$, which is just $L' = M^{-\top} \Bbb{Z}_p$ and $L=M^{-\top} (M^\top M)\Bbb{Z}_p$ has index $|\Bbb{Z}_p/(D)|= p^{v_p(D)}$ in $L'$ where $D=\det(M^\top M)=\det(M)^2$. In $\Bbb{Z}_p/(D)$ we care only of $D$ modulo units of $\Bbb{Z}_p$, we can improve slightly and quotient by squares of units, but the "index of lattice" interpretation will be less obvious.

Comment: Of course I mean $M=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$. When saying $L$ has index $|\Bbb{Z}_p/(D)|$ in $L'$ I'm probably using the Smith normal form whence that $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is a PID (or a Dedekind domain since we can invert all the elements comaximal with $\det(M^\top M)$ to make it a PID..)